# MDPI journal bibtex entries for website not formatting correctly in overleaf

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, mdpi

I am currently writing an article using Overleaf and the MDPI LaTeX template (journal selected: energies). I created a bibtex file using Zotero and exported it to my main-directory in Overleaf. I enabled the external bibliography using

```
%=====================================
% References, variant A: external bibliography
%=====================================
\externalbibliography{yes}
\bibliography{mybib}
```

When citing a website tagged as @misc the references only show the title, but neither the "url" or the "urldate" it was last accessed. I have looked into the mdpi.bst-file and there is a function "format.website", which should take care of the formatting (my guess), but I did not find it to be used anywhere, although it specifies the behavior required.

For example:

```
@misc{national-hydrogen-strategy,
    title = {The {National} {Hydrogen} {Strategy}},
    url = {https://www.bmwi.de/Redaktion/EN/Publikationen/Energie/the-national-hydrogen-strategy.html},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2022-01-04},
    author = {{Federal Ministry for Economic Affairs and Energy}},
    }
```

will only result in:

[image]

the function I was referring to reads:

```
FUNCTION {format.website}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { "" url website *
     urldate empty$
    {"there is url but no urldate in " cite$ * warning$}
    { ", accessed on " * urldate *}
    if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Any help or hint in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: assuming that's https://github.com/jasonfleming/jasgs/blob/master/doc/paper/mdpi.bst then the format.website function is just used in the `www` type, not `misc`

Comment: Oh right! I was not  aware there was a @www type. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that's https://github.com/jasonfleming/jasgs/blob/master/doc/paper/mdpi.bst then the `format.website` function is just used in the `www` type, not `misc`